# Flags number is wrong in chat

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat

http://phpcode.eu/images/1314616335.png

As you can see, there is number "6", but only 1 one flag at [this](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/admin/flagged?show=all) page (10k).

Is it bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 6 is the number of flags, not the number of flagged messages (all 6 flags where for the same message).

Comment: Maybe it could show the number of flags per message in the list, too? This could help against confusion.

Comment: @Paulo exactly..